# Why does GetProperty fail to find it?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I'm trying to use reflection to get a property from a class.  Here is some sample code of what I'm seeing:

```
using System.Reflection;
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] tmp2 = typeof(TestClass).GetProperties();
            PropertyInfo test = typeof(TestClass).GetProperty(
               "TestProp", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public Int32 TestProp
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

When I trace through this, this is what I see:

- When I fetch all properties using `GetProperties()`, the resulting array has one entry, for property `TestProp`.
- When I try to fetch `TestProp` using `GetProperty()`, I get null back.

I'm a little stumped; I haven't been able to find anything in the MSDN regarding `GetProperty()` to explain this result to me.  Any help?

EDIT:

If I add `BindingFlags.Instance` to the `GetProperties()` call, no properties are found, period. This is more consistent, and leads me to believe that `TestProp` is not considered an instance property for some reason.

Why would that be?  What do I need to do to the class for this property to be considered an instance property?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `BindingFlags.Instance` to the `GetProperty` call.

EDIT: In response to comment...

The following code returns the property.

Note: It's a good idea to actually make your property do something before you try to retrieve it (VS2005) :)

```
using System.Reflection;
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] tmp2 = typeof(TestClass).GetProperties();
            PropertyInfo test = typeof(TestClass).GetProperty(
                "TestProp",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public |
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            Console.WriteLine(test.Name);
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public Int32 TestProp
        {
            get
            {
                return 0;
            }
            set
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do that, GetProperties returns nothing as well, which is consistent, in least. But the question is: what do I need to do to find the property with GetProperty? Why isn't TestProp considered an Instance property?

Comment: ...or what do I need to do to class TestClass so that its property appears as an instance property?

Comment: I couldn't duplicate your problem (although I'm using VS2005, so I had to flesh out your property with an implementation).

Comment: I can't either. I copied your sample, removed the property implementation, and all worked fine. Pasted my original example back in, and it was working fine too. Tried a number of things to bring the figure out what I did, with no luck. Oh well, thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Every. Single. Time. (I forget that!)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following tag:

```
System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
```

**EDIT:** This works (at least to me)

```
PropertyInfo test = typeof(TestClass).GetProperty("TestProp", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

Console.WriteLine(test.Name);
```

Comment: See comments to Andrew Rolling's post, above.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong Remi because, with the example you gave to us this works fine ...

Comment: It does for me, now, too.  I can't explain it; blame the user :-)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify whether it is static or an instance (or both) too.

Comment: See comment to Andrew Rolling's post, above.