# visual basic reflection: iterate all methods and properties for given Type

Tags: vb.net, reflection, interface

I am using a library interop.RobotOM, and now i want to list all its classes with their corresponding methods and members

for example for the class RobotApplication I'm trying the following code:

```
Dim myObject As IRobotApplication
myObject = New RobotApplication

For Each prop In myObject.GetType.GetProperties()
    Debug.Print(prop.Name & " " & prop.PropertyType.ToString())
Next

For Each method In myObject.GetType.GetMethods()
    Debug.Print(method .Name & " " & method .ReturnType.ToString())
Next
```

but i get the following output:

```
ToString System.String
GetLifetimeService System.Object
InitializeLifetimeService System.Object
CreateObjRef System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef
Equals System.Boolean
GetHashCode System.Int32
GetType System.Type
```

this is not what i expected, for example the properties Project and version are missing. I want to see following methods and properties:

[link to object browser screenshot](http://www.ttweb.be/robot2.jpg)

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try adding `System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance` to your `.GetProperties()` call. See this answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/360438/3955724.

Comment: thx for the reply, but adding BindingFlags.Instance didn't work. I also tried to get the Property by name [myObject.GetType.GetProperty("Version", BindingFlags.Instance)], but I got a NullReferenceException (de property 'Version' was not found, but as you can see in screenshot it does exist ...)